# Response.Redirect() doesn't work .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, response.redirect

On the button click I am calling a javascript function in the JS function I redirect to an aspx page and in the aspx page I want to redirect to another page (This part is not working).
response.redirect not re-directing, just posting back to current page. Any Idea why it is not working.

Here is my code :

**Review.aspx:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnComplt" runat="server" Text="Complete" OnClientClick ="return compAsgn()" />

function compAsgn() {
       if (window.confirm("Submit all images and complete the assignment?"))
           window.location = "SendImages.aspx?insid=" + $("#IAssignmentId").val() + '&option=complete';
       else
           return false;
```

**SendImages.aspx :**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            assignmentId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["insid"]);
            string url = "Review.aspx?insid" + assignmentId.ToString() + "&viewOption=review";

            string qstrVal = string.Empty;
            qstrVal = Request.QueryString["option"].ToString().ToLower();
            if (qstrVal != null && qstrVal == "complete")
            {
                using (ServiceClient client = new Proxies.ServiceRef.ServiceClient())
                {
                    List<AssignmentInfo> ainfo = new List<AssignmentInfo>();
                    ainfo = client.GetAssignmentInfo(assignmentId);
                    if (ainfo.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (ainfo[0].UploadedCount == 0)
                        {
// AfarSessionData class has a property called ProfileId, which is session variable.  
                            if (AfarSessionData.ProfileId == "000000")
                                url = "Admin.aspx";
                            else
                                url = "HomePage.aspx";
                        }


                    }
                }

            }


            Response.Redirect(url, false);
        }
```

Note : When I debug I do see the control hitting the SendImages page but I see response.redirect not re-directing, just posting back to current page.

Comment: Use fiddler and see what the headers say.  You should have a 302 http status.

Comment: What's the value of url when it gets to that point in the code?

Comment: Admin.aspx is the value of URL

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you're not doing anything to end the request. I'm not an ASP.NET guy, but I *thought* you should either:

- Make the second argument `true` to effectively "hard abort" the request with an exception
- Make the second argument `false`, but then call [`CompleteRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) to stop the rest of the pipeline

Comment: or third option, organize your code so the redirect is the last thing in the code path.

Comment: @Jon thank you. could u pls tell me how to use the EndRequest.

Comment: @BumbleBee: My mistake, it's `CompleteRequest` rather than `EndRequest`. But just call `Response.CompleteRequest`. The thing is, although this may be the last bit of code handling Page_Load, there's still the page processing itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Tried both CompletRequest and Request.End() but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional info related to John Skeets answer:

```
//ends request, no exception, calls Response.End() internally
Response.Redirect (url, true);
```

or

```
try
{
    Response.Redirect (url, false);
}
catch(ThreadAbortException e)
{
    //do whatever you need to
}
```

Here is some info on the issue:

[PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629)

Comment: I'm not sure you can catch a ThreadAbortException from the thread that's been aborted?

Comment: See link, "You can use a try-catch statement to catch this exception."